# gnome-shell next window command line

Tags: gnome-shell

I trying to make a script for window switching by hotkey, and one of the features I would to see is "if selecting window is active, switch to previous window"

i tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
class=$1
command=$2
if xdotool search --classname "$class" > /dev/null ;then
        if xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep -q "WM_CLASS.*\".*$class.*\"";then
                 ### HERE ###
                :#xdotool key --clearmodifiers 'alt+Tab' 
        else
                wmctrl -x -a "$class"
        fi
else
        if [ -n "$command" ];then
                $command &
                disown
        fi
fi
```

after the string marked HERE I tried to just send alt+Tab key to wm, but it works bad, because when I doing this I still holding `ctrl` modifier, which cause switcher to wait (or stall sometime), so I though about just tell gnome to switch window.

So, is there any way to switch back from shell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some extension which does half of the job of my script, forked it, fixed it and add the feature I described above, so I think the question can be closed.

https://github.com/CZ-NIC/run-or-raise/pull/10

in short, I used

```
global.display.get_tab_list(0, null)[1];
```

to get lastWindow, so I focused it using extension api.